# Polymorphism in C - Two "open" functions

Tags: c, polymorphism

I was referring the man page of **open** function in c, and what i saw was that C provides two open functions. Go check man 2 open in terminal.

But what I know of c is that it does not provide polymorphism, or does it?
Help me out folks

Comment: "C provides two open functions" - C doesn't provide any open functions. POSIX does. And it has only one, which is variadic. **You** check the man page.